# What is gravity shearing in molecular cloud rotation?

Tags: gravity, astrophysics

I have read that molecular clouds rotate due to gravitational shearing. What is this phenomenon?

Comment: I've never heard the term gravitational shearing, but shear forces as simply unaligned forces that are applied on one part of a body on a specific direction, and another part of the body in the opposite direction, so I think gravitational shearing will be a similar effect. I found this website which could help you: http://burro.cwru.edu/Academics/Astr221/LifeCycle/starform.html

Comment: The ONLY source of this concept seems to be that link. It's all over the web, word for word. Dodgy?